# Cat pipe mysql : Stopped. What stopped and how can I fix that?

Tags: networking, mysql, pipe

I imported a large database from remote using a cat + mysql command :

```
cat my_db.sql | mysql --host=external_host --user=my_user --password=some_password my_database
```

And after some time, it returned

```
[1]+  Stopped                 cat my_db.sql | mysql --host=external_host --user=my_user --password=some_password my_database
```

What does that mean ? I did the same command with a smaller file and I got a `[1]+  Done`, so clearly, the first try didn't succeed completly, but I don't know what went wrong neither what to do to make it work completely.

Is there a possible solution to that ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Any relevant messages in your logs ?

Comment: I can't access them (It's a shared server with limited access)

Comment: can you bring back the execution to the foreground again (`fg`)?

Comment: I closed the ssh connection since, is it still possible to do that ?

Comment: The shell does not let you logout if there are commands in background. How did you exactly executed the command?

Comment: well, I ssh'd in, then executed the command, it showed the stopped, then I did the other one that showed the Done. Finally, I did a `exit`, and voila.

Answer (score 0):

You have interrupted the command using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

You can bring it back to the foreground using the [`fg`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) commnad.

This is part of the [JOB CONTROL](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) capabilities of the shell.

```
$ man bash
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

```
[2]+  Stopped                 man bash

$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 sudo virt-viewer W7 2>&1 > /dev/null &
[2]+  Stopped                 man bash

$ fg %2
```

Comment: No I didn't stopped it using Ctrl+z :p It stopped all alone !